# Is it possible to have an animated gif work while loading a new page in a webview on ios?

Tags: jquery, ios, swift, webview, animated-gif

The gif animation works fine in browsers, but on my app it doesn’t animate once the user clicks to a new page. It shows and just freezes in whatever state the animation is when the user clicks a link.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

> if you are loading web view inside your app it might work if the same
> behaviour is happening in a browser or try using
> `SafariViewcontroller` if it is working in safari.